# Got an empty $_POST array with a form

Tags: php, file, post, upload

I've got a problem with an empty $_POST array while i'm uploading a file.

Here's the form :

```
<div class="popup">
    <h3>UPLOAD</h3>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            <form
                id="uploadForm"
                method="post" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                action="resources/upload.php?dir=<?php if(isset($_GET['dir'])){echo $_GET['dir'];} ?>" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="file" name="fichier" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
                <label for="file">Choisir un fichier</label><br>
            </form>
            <button onClick="submitUpload();" id="smbtBtt">Uploader</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is the submitUpload fonction :

```
function submitUpload()
{
    if(document.getElementById("file").value != ""){
        document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select a file!");
    }
```

}

Then in the upload.php file, i just var_dump() the array $_FILES and $_POST

It's 6AM in the morning, my 5h straight of programming, so that's why i'm asking :).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you have use var formData= new formdata();  function to get all file data..

Comment: use submit button before form closed..check this change

Comment: @Gulshan Doesn't change anything... :/

Comment: you need to check `$_FILES` rather than $_POST

Comment: You are using **file** type field elements in your form. So you need to use $_FILES instead of $_POST

Comment: @Anant the $FILES is ok. But i need some infos in the $POST one

Comment: @Alteus  use both at the same time no issue, for files you need to use $_FILES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I wasn't able to make the $FILES and the $POST arrays work at the same time, so I find an other solution without one of them. Still tanks to every one.

Comment: what solution you found.There must be some error in your code because of which you are not able to use POST and  FILE at the same time

Comment: in your current code you don't have anything else apart from file and that's why $_POST is empty

Comment: @Anant That's ok, I've resolved it. Now i got some ACL errors ... T_T

Answer (score 1):

Here in your form, you are using file type field element. You have to use '$_FILES' instead of $_POST. Try this

Answer (score 0):

use this code. May be it helps you

```
$('form#uploadForm').submit(function(e){
    var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
url: "upload_file.php",            
type: "POST",
data:  formData,
mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData:false,
success: function(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Can I still use my fields as before ?

Comment: @Alteus check formData variable..it get your all data of input fileds

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="popup">
    <h3>UPLOAD</h3>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            <form
                id="uploadForm"
                method="post" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                action="resources/upload.php?dir=<?php if(isset($_GET['dir'])){echo $_GET['dir'];} ?>" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="file" name="fichier" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
                <label for="file">Choisir un fichier</label><br>
            </form>
            <button onClick="submitUpload();" id="smbtBtt">Uploader</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitUpload()
{
    if(document.getElementById("file").value != ""){
        document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select a file!");
    }
}
</script>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php
$test=$_FILES["fichier"]["tmp_name"];

echo $test;
```

?>

Comment: I need to user the POST methode. You can't transfer files with the GET one. And It's my POST array in php that is empty..

Comment: you can get $_GET['fichier'] using get method.. if you are using POST method i will update answer as soon as possible